# Draw grid on top of model on each face

Tags: three.js

I am a beginner in ThreeJS. I have spent quite a number of hours to figure out my requirements hence as a last venue I am here.

I am loading a 3D Shipping Container model using OBJLoader. I have added OrbitControls to rotate the camera.

My next task is to draw a grid on the required side of the model for the given number of cells and then highlight/shade particular cell with a given color.
The grid has to be fit within the length & height of the object side.

Please do give me guidelines/steps on how to achieve the above.

Any code samples would be great. I have gone through almost all of the ThreeJS Samples but none suits my requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thanks. I have already gone through the links you have given. I have not attached any verifiable example because I have completed only OBJ loading and added OrbitControls. There is nothing much beyond this. Only if I receive some guidelines from the experts then I can move forward.

When I receive the guidelines to achieve my requirements then I can try and create code in JSFiddle.

Comment: You can ask this question on the forum: https://discourse.threejs.org/